# Powershell Checkpoint as Job or Workflow

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-workflow

Afternoon, 
I'm in the process of writing a powershell script to replace a file in 600 - 1000 folders. I've got process down and tested it on a small number of folders.

As its updating a large number of folders, it will probably run as a scheduled task overnight.
Is it possible to create checkpoint when the script stops, and then for it to start from that checkpoint when the script runs again.

For exmaple -

1. Script runs for 4 hours
2. Creates CheckPoint
3. Stops

Next day

4. Continues from previous checkpoint....

I've tried creating a file which gets updated when folders are changed, then using this as a 'exclude' folder. But wondered if there is an better solution.

Comment: Perhaps if you have access to a web platform like SharePoint you could record the starting stopping point on a list item or similar record there.  Or even record it in a database directly (depending on if you would like to publish it for others to see or just be known to the processes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's any built-in function/class to do this, but this can be achieved by logging what the script is doing. 
 The general idea would be store all the folders that have been processed in a log file and the next time you run it you can skip the folder if it is listed in the file.